# Google Chart tools date format

Tags: javascript, api, charts

I'm using Google Chart tools API, and I'm trying to make a [line chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart), of data coming from the database, which works fine so far.

But now since the chart is about the "body mass index" of a user, I want the x-axis being time formatted. By that I mean, the spacing between each date should correspond the actual time lapsed.

I hope I made myself understand.

The incoming data types from the DB are:

- body mass index (real) (for the y-axis);
- date (date) (for the x-axis).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the [annotated timeline](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline) (from Google Chart API).

Here's a simple code example...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Body Mass Index');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2012, 9 ,2), 20],
    [new Date(2012, 10 ,5), 22],
    [new Date(2012, 11 ,4), 24],
    [new Date(2013, 0 ,12), 23]
  ]);

  var annotatedtimeline = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  annotatedtimeline.draw(data);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, as the link may eventually break and the meaning of the answer will be lost. Better to quote or summarize the source along with the link.